# Checking row-by-row if a value in one column is present as a substring of a value in another column, appending the string if the boolean value = False

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to improve the quality of the title descriptions of some of the items listed in a product feed by creating a function which loops through existing fields and checks whether these items are present.

If the value in the column is not present, I wish to append the item into the existing title at the start of the title.

So far, I have tried multiple methods including using boolean values to see if the value is true or false. However, beyond this point I'm unable to use this to loop through each row and append the string if FALSE.

Here is some sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
feed = pd.read_csv(r'...feed.csv')
cols = ['title', 'color', 'brand']
df = feed.loc[:,cols]
```

## Output

```py
title   color   brand
0   Testy Black Jumper  black   Testy
1   White T-Shirt   white   Testy_New
2   Testy Red Jacket    red Testy
3   Trousers    green   Testy
```

## Attempt 1 (Does not work)

```py
def brand_checker(df):
    for row in df:
        if row in df[~df['title'].isin(df['brand']):
            m = df.filter(like='title').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(str(df['brand'])), axis=1).all(axis=1)
            df['new_title'] = np.where(m, df['title'], df['brand'] + " " + df['title'])
        else:
            pass
    return df

df2 = brand_checker(df)
df.head(3)
```

At the moment I am getting the following error message:

"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

## Expected Output:

```py
title   color   brand
0   Testy Black Jumper  black   Testy
1   Testy White T-Shirt white   Testy
2   Testy_New Red Jacket    red Testy_New
3   Testy Trousers  green   Testy
```

How am I able to check row-by-row if the brand is currently present in the title (order does not matter) and then append to the start if not?

Ideally, I would like to replicate the process for color and/or any other columns which may be added into the dataframe in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have better luck with something like this. I noticed you had some str conversion going on in there, so if your data types aren't str already, you may have to add some conversion to this.

```py
def brand_checker(df):
    for x in range(len(df.iloc[:])):
        if df.iloc[x,2] not in df.iloc[x,0]:
           df.iloc[x,2] = df.iloc[x,2] + " " + df.iloc[x,0]
    return df

df2 = brand_checker(df)
df.head(3)
```

Comment: @ slr1337 that makes sense to me, however, when I execute the code I get "KeyError: 0" ... can you think of why this error is being raised?

Comment: It is something to do with your data. Key error 0 would mean that there is no 0 key. You may be having an issue with your data itself. Try adding print(df) before the loop and see what is printed. I'm not familiar with pandas, so that could be the issue too.

Comment: Try using df.iloc[[x], [0]]                                          https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/